# How do I get the Identity field that results from an insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm going to insert data into a table like so:

```
Insert Into MyTable (Field1, Field2)
           Values   ('test', 5)
```

When that insert occurs, the new row is going to have an identify value in the `ID` column.  If have a variable called `@ID` in my T-SQL code, how do I populate `@ID` with the result of the T-SQL Insert?

```
Declare @ID int

Insert into MyTable (Field1, Field2)
             Values ('test', 5)

--//How do I populate @ID with the value of ID of the record that was just inserted?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways - the first is to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @ID INT

INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2)
VALUES ('test', 5)

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Don't use @@IDENTITY -- the value it contains is for the last updated IDENTITY column without regard for scope.  Meaning, it's not reliable that it holds the value for *your* INSERT, but SCOPE_IDENTITY does.

The other alternative is to use the [OUTPUT clause](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315115233/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+).

Comment: Ooh.  I'm glad I read this.  Thanks for the explanation about the difference between `@@Identity` and `Scope_Identity()`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use scope_identity in your case.

There are different ways to get last inserted identity and they differ in how they work just for your information listing them -

1. [@@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. [IDENT_CURRENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
4. [OUTPUT CLAUSE](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315115233/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx)  (came to know about it from @OMG Ponies answer)

Consider the [differences](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) and [comparisons](https://web.archive.org/web/20130501032809/http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/output-clause-%E2%80%93-a-great-alternative-to-scope_identity/) between them before deciding which one to use.

Comment: @@identity and ident_current should never be used for this purpose. @@identity will return the incorrect value if a trigger is placed on the table which inserts to a table with an identity. ident_current is even more dangerous because it gets the last identity used by any connection and can easily result in data integrity problems that almost impossible to find and fix.