# how to get the new identity ID just after inserting the new row in Sql Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, web-services

I have a set of tables which are connected through foreign keys , and almost all of them have the primary keys as auto increment identifier of sql server. The figure is given below .

Now when I am adding a row in storyboard table I need to know the auto generated storyboard Id on inserting the row so that using that I can insert the slides associated with it into slide table.

For this should I query the database for the Id created or is there any other way to use this ? Please tell me how to do this in sql server 2008

I am using asp dot net web service to interact with sql server.

[image: Database Design]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the Identity field that results from an insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157142/how-do-i-get-the-identity-field-that-results-from-an-insert)

Comment: @Richard:Thanks for pointing that out,but I was looking for a asp.net example, it is not there in that post

Comment: The answer is not affected by the type of application (use of an ORM or specific data access approach would be significant but since you don't mention anything specific...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [scope_identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). And if you use SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2005 you can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause of the [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answering , i also found a useful link with an example doing the same .

http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20110625074412/http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx